# Returning View with Specific Route Name (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am returning View based on a specific value. There are two different routes that can serve that View. How can i specify route Name in

```
 this.return View(mymodel);

  var defaultRoute = Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { action = "abc", controller = "xyz", id = viewModel.Id });
```

I have couple of routes. How can i specify route name while returning a view